# How to perform Spatial Query to remove features that intersect/touch/overlap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, spatial-query

I have two polygon layers and many of the features are identical (or should be identical). I want to isolate only the features that are in one layer but not the other.

I'm using QGIS 3 and I tried using the Vector>Geoprocessing>Difference tool but it left me with slivers of features because they weren't perfectly identical.

[image: One fully drawn building along with many slivers of buildings]

I used this layer with slivers by eliminating all features with an area ~0, but I'd still like to know if there's a Spatial Query I should be running.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but maybe the `Select by location` tool will help you.

Comment: Yes, `Select by location` was what I needed, specifically the "removing from current selection".

Answer (score 1):

csk gave me the solution in a comment. I selected all features in a layer then used `Select by location` and `removing from selection` to remove the features that were matched by another layer. Repeated the task vice versa to get all the features that were unique.